VBA Excel Change Calendar Shape Colour According to ItemName
I have this code please see below, that allows shapes to be added to a calendar, someone fills in excel spreadsheet column under calendar item name for example residential to prepare, or induction or marking and moderation so whatever the item name I would like to assigned all inductions the same colour shape and all residentials the same colour shape at present all the shapes are coloured the same please see the code below.  I do not know how to do this, please advise:
Sub Calendar_Refresh()
'Clear all existing item shapes from Calendar sheet
For Each ItemShp In Calendar.Shapes
    If InStr(ItemShp.Name, "CalItem") > 0 Then ItemShp.Delete
Next ItemShp
ItemColor = Admin.Range("F7").Interior.Color 'Set Item Shape Color
ItemNumb = 1 'Set default item # to 1
With ItemsDB
    LastRow = .Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Item Row
    If LastRow < 4 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    .Range("A3:F" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("I2:J3"),           CopyToRange:=.Range("M2:o2"), Unique:=True
    LastResultRow = .Range("M99999").End(xlUp).Row
    If LastResultRow < 3 Then Exit Sub
    If LastResultRow < 4 Then GoTo NoSort
     With .Sort
     .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ItemsDB.Range("O3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,     DataOption:=xlSortNormal  'Sort Based On Date
     .SetRange ItemsDB.Range("M3:o" & LastResultRow) 'Set Range
     .Apply 'Apply Sort
     End With
NoSort:
    For ResultRow = 3 To LastResultRow
        ItemID = .Range("M" & ResultRow).Value 'item ID
        ItemName = .Range("N" & ResultRow).Value 'Item Name
        ItemDate = .Range("O" & ResultRow).Value 'Item Date
       DayItemCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([ItemDate_Results], ItemDate) 'Get # of   Items in a single Date
        If DayItemCount > 7 Then DayItemCount = 7 'Set Item Limit to 7
        For CalRow = 4 To 51 Step 8
            For CalCol = 4 To 12
                If Calendar.Cells(CalRow, CalCol).Value = ItemDate Then 'Day Found
                    Calendar.Shapes("SampleItemShp").Duplicate.Name = "CalItem" & ItemID
                    With Calendar.Shapes("CalItem" & ItemID)
                        .Left = Calendar.Cells(CalRow, CalCol).Left 'Set Left Pos.
                        .Top = Calendar.Cells(CalRow + ItemNumb, CalCol).Top + 1
                        .Width = Calendar.Cells(CalRow + ItemNumb, CalCol).Width
                        .Height = Calendar.Cells(CalRow + ItemNumb, CalCol).Height
                        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ItemName 'Text inside shape
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ItemColor 'Set Item Color
                        .OnAction = "Calendar_Item_Select" 'Macro to select item
                    End With
                    If ItemNumb >= DayItemCount Then
                        ItemNumb = 1 'Reset
                    Else
                        ItemNumb = ItemNumb + 1 'Increment by 1
                    End If
               End If
            Next CalCol
          Next CalRow
    Next ResultRow
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I tried removing interior colour altogether so I could change and set conditional formatting instead, but, I could not do it correctly, it just removed the shape altogether.  I tried changing the admin range to cover "F7" and "F8" so one had the item name and the other the color that did not work.
